# Safari css height: auto; and height: 100%; stretches image. Does not happen in firefox or chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, grid-layout

I have square images in a grid. The css says the width of each is 25%. The height should be set to auto. What you should get is a row of 4 straight across. What I get instead is width: 25%; height: max-image size

[This fiddle might explain what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/9zocbot2/)

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>

#container img {width: 25%; height: auto;}
```

In firefox and chrome it looks fine. I can't figure out what the issue is in safari

Comment: Its unclear of what issue you are facing, it works well for me. Can you share a screenshot or some more details.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/TkZCB) is what the difference looks like for me. the images show up as squares in chrome, whereas in safari, the height is way off. I have it set at auto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the fiddle example I see that the for `'figure img'` selectors `min-height` property is set to `100%` which makes the image stretch its height to the whole block. Remove that and it would work.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you I was stuck on this forever